# How do I check if an Object has been initialized/created in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object

So I have the following class...

```
class Pet
{
    public:
        Pet() : id(0),
            name("New Pet")
        {

        }

        Pet(const int new_id, const std::string new_name) : id(new_id),
            name(new_name)
        {

        }

        Pet(const Pet new_pet) : id(new_pet.id),
            name(new_pet.name)
        {

        }
    private:
        const int id;
        const std::string name;
};
```

Somewhere in my code I then create a instance of this class like so...

```
Pet my_pet = Pet(0, "Henry");
```

Later on in my code, an event is supposed to cause this pet to be deleted.
    delete(my_pet);

How do I check if my_pet has been initialized...

Would something like this work?

```
if(my_pet == NULL)
{
    // Pet doesn't exist...
}
```

Comment: `my_pet` doesn't need to be deleted as it is non a dynamically allocated object. Do you mean `Pet* my_pet = new Pet(0, "Henry");` ?

Comment: You should probably be taking your `const Pet` and `const std::string` arguments as reference, here `Pet(const Pet new_pet)` and here `Pet(const int new_id, const std::string new_name)` for efficiency, there's not a need to copy data here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean

```
Pet* my_pet = new Pet(0, "Henry");
```

instead of `Pet my_pet = Pet(0, "Henry");`
You can initialise your `Pet` object to `NULL` (or `nullptr` for C++11) like so:

```
Pet* pet = NULL; // or nullptr
```

and later assign it an instance of `Pet`:

```
pet = new Pet(0, "Henry");
```

This allows you to check the value of `pet` without invoking undefined behaviour (through uninitialised variables):

```
if (pet == NULL) // or nullptr
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks @Levi.

How would I go about forcing the deletion of the pet...

For example, Say a Pet was assigned to my_pet. But at some point I want to make my_pet not hold a pet.

Would this work...?
 
    my_pet = NULL;

Comment: you can just call `delete pet`

Comment: @Ricky _"should work great then. "_ No, i don't really think so. You shouldn't need to manage `new`/´delete` on your own. Use smart pointers, as mentioned with my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

`delete(my_pet);` doesn't make sense, neither by the signature used (should be `delete my_pet;`, if valid).

With your code

```
Pet my_pet = Pet(0, "Henry");
```

no dynamic memory allocation was involved, thus you don't ever need to call `delete my_pet;`

The object instance will be destroyed as soon the scope where you called `Pet my_pet = Pet(0, "Henry");` is left.

---

As for your comment *"How would I go about forcing the deletion of the pet."*, you should use [dynamic memory management smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), rather calling `new Pet()` and bothering about *forcing* deletion yourself.

If you really need dynamic memory allocation for `Pet`, rather use something like

```
std::unique_ptr<Pet> my_pet(new Pet(0, "Henry"));`
```

Comment: `delete(my_pet)` is perfectly valid

Comment: @Levi Sure?? You did notice that `my_pet` isn't even a pointer variable, didn't you?

Comment: well, if `delete my_pet` is valid, it is safe to assume that `delete (my_pet)` is too

Comment: oh wait my bad, I misread the answer to mean 'you should use `delete my_pet`  instead of `delete (my_pet)`